# What is expected true error?

Tags: variance, cross-validation, bootstrap, bias

In [1] and [2], the authors give formulas for the *expected true error* of various resampling protocols (CV, bootstrap) associated with a score function *Q*. I'm not sure to understand exactly what is this notion. In particular, does is it have any relationship with the *bias* of CV (or boostrap) as an estimator of *Q*? Can this be used to detect under/overfitting (with a measure of variance)?

References:

[1] "Cross-Validation, the Jacknife, and the Bootstrap: Excess Error Estimation in Forward Logistic Regression", Gong G., Journal of the American Statistical Association, 1986

[2] "Improvements on Cross-Validation: The .632+ Bootstrap Method", Efron B. and Tibshirani R., Journal of the American Statistical Association, 1997